# Getting all values of a table column angular

Tags: jquery

I have a table which contains 4 columns and the number of rows will be dynamic. The table contains many values and hence the table is paginated on 20 pages. The first column is of checkbox input which the user may check or uncheck in order to select a row. On button click I need the values of all the checked checkboxes in the table on any page.
Right now I am using the following code to populate the array with the values of selected checkboxes.

```
$('#tableExmp tbody input[type="checkbox"]:checked').each(function () {
      var companyObj = {};
      companyObj['id'] = $(this).attr('id');
      companyObj['value'] = $(this).attr('value');

      selectedCompanies.push(companyObj);
    });
```

Using the above code, I only get the values from the current page. How can I get all values of checked checkboxes from all pages on which the table is paginated?

Comment: Are you sure you are using Angular ? from the above code seems like you are jquery to select.. How is your table displayed ?

Comment: I am basically using jquery in angular. Table is displayed like first column is of checkboxes, second column is of entity name and so on.

Comment: slightly off track but you might want to consider angular material table  https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview .. here data source will come out of the box including click all.

Answer (score 0):

You should add one more parameter to your each object in array rather than using jquery in angular. One attribute create as `isSelected` as default `false`
then create one general checkox value an give it a `change` or `click` event and assign all array object attribute value with this checkbox value